# Enabling HTTPS support on Tumblr blogs

Tags: http, ssl, https, tumblr, insecure-connection

I am trying to work out if there is a way to link to a Tumblr blog over HTTPS/SSL.

When I link to [my blog](https://crmpicco.tumblr.com/) with HTTPS I can't access it, but it works under HTTP.

I came across [this post on TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/03/tumblr-adds-support-for-ssl-but-doesnt-turn-it-on-by-default/) from Feb 2014, which suggests that there is a config setting to turn it on, but it would appear this no longer exists.

> According to Tumblr, the feature has been in testing for “weeks” now,
>   and today is available in Tumblr’s settings. To enable it, users have
>   to go to their Tumblr dashboard’s Account Settings, then toggle the
>   switch, so to speak.

Comment: The switch they're talking about was for the dashboard only. It used to be optional, whereas now it's default.

Comment: @Ally Thanks for confirming. I have received a reply from Tumblr support. See my "answer" below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reply from Tumblr support:

> Hello,
>
> Sorry, but what you’ve asked about isn’t supported at this time. We’ll
>   share your desire for this feature with the rest of our team. Thanks
>   Doug
>
> Tumblr.com Support.

Answer (score 13):

SSL on blogs is now available! [This post from Tumblr support](http://support.tumblr.com/post/138103206102/ssl-security-which-has-been-available-on-the) has the deets.

Basically, you can go into settings -> your blog and there should be an option to turn it on:

[image]